# Javascript Key/Value in ArrayList

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning to use key/value arrays and object/properties.

I have an arrayList of items.

```
var itemList = [firstitem, seconditem];
```

How do I give each itemList properties?

```
itemList[0].name = "pear";
itemList[0].value = "$5";
```

Is this correct?

```
var items = [ 
      { 
          "name": "pear",
          "value": "$2"
      }, {
          "name": "apple",
          "value": "$5"
      }];
```

Comment: looks perfectly all right.

Comment: Just paste it in your Browser Console then print the value of `items`.

Answer (score 3):

That’s the most common way if you want to initialize an array with predefined objects as items. You could also do it like this:

```
var items = [];
items[0] = {
    "name": "pear",
    "value": "$2"
};
items[1] = …
```

or

```
var items = [];
items[0] = {};
items[0].name = "pear";
items[0].value = "$2";

items[1] = …
```

Answer (score 2):

Well here is http://jsfiddle.net/coolbhushans/3ubhnedm/ the js fiddle of the same

```
var items = [ 
      { 
          "name": "pear",
          "value": "$2"
      }, {
          "name": "apple",
          "value": "$5"
      }];

alert("1st name "+items[0].name +"\t second name " +items[1].name);
alert("1st value "+items[0].value+ "\t second value"+ items[1].value );
```